cs2 deathmatch unselect primary weapon
When I play deathmatch and selecting different weapons throughout the match I keep both primary and secondary weapons enabling me to switch between them during a deathmatch game. However, I recently played a match where I only wanted to use a pistol (secondary weapon) but had accidentally selected a primary weapon in the menu at some point. The problem is that when you respawn you start with the primary weapon selected. This meant I had to frantically hit the 2 key after spawning each time and sometimes when it gets hectic this lead to me dying a few times unnecessarely.
So my question is: is there a way to "unselect" the primary weapon or a setting to switch to primary by default after respawn?

I tested it out briefly. Could not find any way to do so. :(

When reading the documentation of the mp_ct_default_primary we can see how it works:
mp_ct_default_primary <Weapon Code(s)>

This command sets the default primary weapon that counter terrorists spawn with at the start of the round. Default is none (0).
So when we run this command, it should reset to 'No weapon'
mp_ct_default_primary 0

Documentation
